# Where does Java save files to?

Tags: java, java-io

I ran the below code and created a file. Where can I find it in my filesystem?

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReaderDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File f = new File ("wayback.txt");
        f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(f.exists());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your program, run it and it'll show you the expected location:

```
System.out.println(f.getCanonicalFile());
```